# Is there a way to assign group according registration source?

Tags: keycloak, user-registration, idp

I try to figure out how to, automatically, assign a default group according the user source.

I am using keycloak 22.0

I have two sources of users:

- users coming from an AD authenticated through an identity provider (google, azure, …)
- users coming from a self registration process

I want to dispatch the users in two distinct groups according the origin (*GROUP_AD* or *GROUP_SELF_REGISTER*). Is it possible to setup such behavior ?

Note:

- in the “identity providers” menu, a default provider group is defined via an Identity Provider Hardcoded Mapper
- in the “realm settings”, a default group is defined via the “User registration” tab

Thanks for your help